# HttpWebRequest Post Method sending partial Data

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post

I have the following code to send a POST request to Server.

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
myWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
myWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(data);
writer.Close();
```

The data to be posted is an XML request with nearly 2000 Characters. I read the response as shown below.

```
this.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream);
string responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The response data that we are obtaining above has only a portion of the actual data send.

Please help me to get the full data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, i think you miss the Encoding... using this i'm sending huge xml to server

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        //Console.WriteLine("Service Status Code:"+((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've been doing it is only slightly different than your way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentLength = DataToPost.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(DataToPost);
writer.Close();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

This way has been working for years.